# comparing two normally distributed random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

In a large corporation, people over age thirty have an annual income whose distribution can be approximated by a normal distribution with mean 60,000 and standard deviation 10,000. The incomes of those under age thirty are also approximately normal, but with mean 40,000 and standard deviation 10,000. One person is selected at random from those over thirty, and independently, one person is selected at random from those under thirty.

a) What is the chance that the younger's income exceeds the older?

b) What is the chance that the smaller of the two incomes in a) exceeds 50,000?

Answer (score 1):

For a), you're looking for $P(X_2 -X_1)>0$ , where $X_2$ is the random variable "Salary of population over thirty; similar for $X_1$. You need to figure out how to obtain this distribution ( Hint: find the distribution for -$X_2$, then : what result do you know that is used to find the distribution of a sum of random variables? ). For 2) Find the z-value of $50,000$ and look up a chart for the standard normal.

Comment: So after I find the distribution for part a, I can use the same distribution for part b? This doesn't seem correct to me, though, since in part a I am looking for the joint distribution, while part b is looking at just one of the variables.

Comment: No; in the first case, you're looking for the distribution of the variable $X_1-X_2$ --the difference of the salaries; in the second case, you're interested in the salary of the second population, because you're asked about the probability of someone in that population having a certain salary.

Comment: But it might be possible that the chosen individual from the over 30 population's income is less than that of the under 30 individual, so I can't simply rely on that one distribution. Thoughts?

Comment: In the first case, you're not relying on one distribution; you're considering the distribution of the difference of salaries of the two populations , which is equivalent to the probability that the salary of the younger is higher than the older, i.e., that the difference of the salaries is negative. This probability can be obtained from the distributions of the salaries of each of the populations.  For the second case, you're only interested in the distribution of salaries of the under-thirty group.

Comment: For the second case, we are interested in the probability that the smaller of the two incomes is greater than 50,000. Since we have an individual from the under 30 group and an individual from the over 30 group, it might be possible that the individual from the under 30 group has an income greater than that of the over 30. So I don't think I can assume that the under 30 person has the smallest income... I'm not sure how to account for both scenarios, however,

Comment: My apologies: I misread the second question. The issue here is one of  conditional probability: what is p(X_1=50,000| X_2>X_1) , where X_1 is the older population, and X_2 is the younger one.